# javax.jms.MessageNotReadableException: Message body is write-only

Tags: serialization, jms, activemq-classic, amqp

Am having a weird problem

ActiveMQ is the messaging server and am using AMQP for sending messages

When I have both the publisher and subscriber in the same eclipse project. I can send send ObjectMessage and receive without any problem

But , when I split the subscriber and publisher to two different eclipse project, am getting

```
javax.jms.MessageNotReadableException: Message body is write-only
```

This is my Class of the object am sending

```
public class Test1 implements Serializable{

    private String x;

    public Test1( String x){
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

And this is the exception

```
javax.jms.MessageNotReadableException: Message body is write-only
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.checkWriteOnlyBody(ActiveMQBytesMessage.java:863)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.initializeReading(ActiveMQBytesMessage.java:868)
        at org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQBytesMessage.getBodyLength(ActiveMQBytesMessage.java:190)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.jms.AMQPNativeOutboundTransformer.transform(AMQPNativeOutboundTransformer.java:63)
        at org.apache.qpid.proton.jms.AutoOutboundTransformer.transform(AutoOutboundTransformer.java:37)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter$ConsumerContext.pumpOutbound(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:751)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter$ConsumerContext.onMessageDispatch(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:710)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpProtocolConverter.onActiveMQCommand(AmqpProtocolConverter.java:300)
        at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpTransportFilter.oneway(AmqpTransportFilter.java:64)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.dispatch(TransportConnection.java:1378)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.processDispatch(TransportConnection.java:897)
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.iterate(TransportConnection.java:943)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:129)
        at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

This is the Code am following

https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/activemq/trunk/activemq-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/JMSClientTest.java?r=1406466&r=1414990

Comment: what does the code where the exception is thrown look like?  What is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Message m = consumer.receive()
ObjectMessage o = (ObjectMessage)m; //exception here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supposed to be a bug in ActiveMQ with AMQ

This error happens under two reproducible  conditions

1. Sending object as message (Currently cannot send Object)
2. When the consumer encounters some exceptions

The notable thing here is

**This is in no way affects the message being transmitted. You will just see the exception but the data transport will work fine!!!**

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug, open a Jira issue on the ActiveMQ site and post a test case, I don't think there's any magic switch here to fix the exception.  Without posting your code that's all we can say.

Comment: https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/activemq/trunk/activemq-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/amqp/JMSClientTest.java?r=1406466&r=1414990

This is the code am following!